# Aligning lists of structs for patch analysis

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, sequence-alignment

I am currently reverse engineering a regularly updated multiplayer game. The networking protocol uses a custom serialization framework and I am now able to restore a lot of information about the messages that are being exchanged. For each message I can retrieve the complete structure of said message and the type of that message (eg. Authentication, Chat, Movement...). However one problem I am having is that messages and message types are regularly added and removed and also messages might have fields added or removed. **The overall order of messages and message types stays the same**!

I am now looking for a way of how to best utilize the information I have to match the updated message structures to the old ones where I have already identified the meaning of some messages and fields. That is, given two sets of messages like the following how can I transfer the information that was already reverse engineered (comments in the new messages)?

Old Messages:

```
Authentication:
 message Login:
  opcode: 1
  fields:
  - string mail
  - string password

 message LoginResponse:
  opcode: 2
  fields:
  - string token

Chat:
 message ChatSend:
  opcode: 3
  fields:
  - string channel
  - string message
 message ChatReceive:
  opcode: 4
  fields:
  - string channel
  - string user
  - string message
```

New Messages:

```
Type1: # Authentication
 message Unk1: # Login
  opcode: 1
  fields:
  - string unk1 # mail
  - string unk2 # password
  _ string unk3 # new field
  
 message Unk2: # LoginResponse
  opcode: 2
  fields:
  - string unk1 # token

Type2: # new Type
  message Unk3:
   opcode: 3
   fields:
   - Vec3 unk1
   - float unk2

Type3: # Chat
 message Unk4: # ChatSend
  opcode: 4
  fields:
  - string unk1 # channel
  - string unk2 # message
 message Unk5: # new message
  opcode: 5
  fields:
  - string unk1
  - string unk2
 message Unk6: # ChatReceive
  opcode: 6
  fields:
  - string unk1 # channel
  - string unk2 # user
  - string unk3 # message
```

Some additional information: There are around 60 different types of messages and per message type there are at most around 100 messages. Also I would welcome solutions either in pseudo code or python.

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: Guild Wars 2 https://www.guildwars2.com/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better and more sustainable solution is to redesign the system that produces the messages to be consistent with the names and format. That would make it more extensible.

If that is really not an option, here is a possible algorithm you might want to explore by calculating the string differences using a library such as [Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/Levenshtein/). Here, let's focus on the outermost data (the types). Just perform the same concept on the inner data (the messages and fields).

Let's say these are the matches between the types in the old and new messages:

| Old Messages | New Messages | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | N1 |  |
|  | N2 | new |
|  | N3 | new |
| O2 | N4 |  |
| O3 | N5 |  |
| O4 |  | deleted |
| O5 |  | deleted |
|  | N6 | new |
| O6 | N7 |  |
|  | N8 | new |

Where:

- An example of Old Message e.g. `O1`:

```
Authentication:
 message Login:
  opcode: 1
  fields:
  - string mail
  - string password
```

- An example of New Message e.g. `N1`:

```
Type1:
 message Unk1:
  opcode: 1
  fields:
  - string unk1
  - string unk2
  - string unk3
```

For each old message, calculate the Levenshtein distance to each new message and select the smallest distance. The smallest distance signifies it is the closest equivalent string. Let's assume the numbers below were the calculated distances per `Ox` : `Ny` pair

| O# | N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 | N6 | N7 | N8 | Smallest Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | 3 | 10 | 7 | 11 | 14 | 8 | 5 | 12 | N1 |
| O2 | 8 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 17 | N4 |
| O3 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 3 | 13 | 7 | 6 | N5 |
| O4 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 15 | 16 | 6 | 3 | 10 | N7 |
| O5 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 11 | 4 | 10 | 5 | N6 |
| O6 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 14 | 1 | 11 | N7 |

But since the order of messages stays the same, `O4` mapping to `N7` while `O5` mapping to the earlier `N6` is wrong. Also `O6` is wrong as it maps to the same `N7`. Now we have to perform additional steps before choosing the smallest distance

- Check if an earlier `O` is mapped to an `N` that is either equal or later than the currently chosen `N` e.g. here is `O5` mapping to `N6` when an earlier `O4` is mapped to a later `N7`.

  - If there is, check if **all** of those earlier `O` are closer to their mapped `N` than the current one.

    - If all of those earlier `O` are closer to their `N`, then we can't change that because its similarity is closer than the current. Instead, we would try to choose the 2nd smallest distance to the current `O` and repeat the same steps.
    - But if the current `O` is mapped closer to the currently chosen `N` than any of the earlier `O` to their respective `N`, then we would choose the currently chosen `N` for the current `O`. Then we would mark all earlier `O` that uses an equal or later `N` as already deleted.

With this additional steps, the updated table would be:

| O# | N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 | N6 | N7 | N8 | Smallest Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | 3 | 10 | 7 | 11 | 14 | 8 | 5 | 12 | N1 |
| O2 | 8 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 17 | N4 |
| O3 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 3 | 13 | 7 | 6 | N5 |
| O4 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 15 | 16 | 6 | 3 | 10 | <s>N7</s> Deleted |
| O5 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 11 | 4 | 10 | 5 | <s>N6</s> <s>N8</s> Deleted |
| O6 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 14 | 1 | 11 | N7 |

As you can see, `O5` was remapped from `N6` (distance of 4) to `N8` (distance of 5) since `O4` used a later `N7`. But then both were marked as deleted because `O6` was mapped to `N7` which is closer (distance of 1) to the earlier `O` that used an `N` equal or later than `N7` (namely `O4` and `O5`).

Now, we know that:

- `O1` is `N1`
- `O2` is `N4`
- `O3` is `N5`
- `O4` is deleted
- `O5` is deleted
- `O6` is `N7`
- While all unchosen `N` are newly added namely `N2`, `N3`, `N6`, `N8`

Comment: Hmm yeah that is close to what I had in mind as well. What do you mean with making the messages more consistent? The whole point of this is that I do not have control over the structure of the messages and the names are not available. I can however dump the structure into any format you think might be easier to work with. I just chose yaml for readability.

Comment: _"redesign the system that produces the messages to be consistent with the names and format"_ I believe when I stated this, I didn't take into account that the whole point of this is to do reverse engineering, which of course it wouldn't be formatted :D Sorry for the confusion. Then, seems like your usage of YAML is the best option. Using JSON would add additional characters to compare thus might be additional complexity, depends on the algorithm :)